# TypeError: Type string calldata slice is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory

Tags: solidity, string, solidity-0.7.x

I want to slice a string and save it to a memory or storage variable.

Is this possible?

```
function test(string calldata _input) external{        
    string memory something = _input[1:3];
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Type string calldata slice is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory
```

Comment: Well then cast it from `calldata` to `memory`.

Comment: I am trying, but slicing is only available for calldata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly cast it to a `string memory` by wrapping it in `string()`:

```
  function test(string calldata _input) external{        
    string memory something = string(_input[1:3]);
  }
```